# entity framework inserting multiple objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am trying to insert multiple objects into my db.

`foreach (employee employeedata in employeelist)
                { objectcontext.employees.AddObject(employeedata); } objectcontext.SaveChanges();`

I call objectcontext.savechanges outside the loop so that it is efficient. 
The problem is that I would like to get a list of primary keys that are generated by the db.

If I am inserting a single object using `objectcontext.employees.AddObject(employeeA)` I could get the id after saving changes as `employeeA.id`. I am not sure of how to go about this now that I am adding a list of objects to the object context and then calling savechanges that inserts these into the db. Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just iterate through your list again and check Ids. If you are using autogenerated column in DB, Ids will be filled.

Answer (score 1):

do some thing like this

```
foreach (employee employeedata in employeelist)
{
 employeeA.id // Will give you id
}
```